How does $\delta \theta_1 = \frac{\Delta v \delta t}{\Delta x}$?
In matrix form, the rate-of-strain tensor is:
\begin{equation}
\{e_{ij}\} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
e_{11} & e_{12} & e_{13} \\
e_{21} & e_{22} & e_{23} \\
e_{31} & e_{32} & e_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x_1} \right) & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x_3} + \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial x_1} \right) \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x_2} \right) & \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x_2} & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x_3} + \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial x_2} \right) \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x_3} \right) & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x_3} \right) & \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial x_3}
\end{pmatrix}
\label{1.2.10}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right) & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \right) \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \right) \\
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \right) & \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \right) & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
First, the diagonal terms. It is easy to see that $e_{11} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is the rate of stretching per unit length in the direction of $x$, $e_{22} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ is the rate of stretching per unit length in the direction of $y$, and $e_{33} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$ is the rate of stretching per unit length in the direction of $z$. They are the normal components of the rate of strain tensor.
Note that
\begin{equation}
e_{11} + e_{22} + e_{33} = e_{kk} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}
\label{1.2.11}
\end{equation}
is the rate of volume dilatation due to fluid motion. For a proof, let us consider a cube with sides $(x, x + \Delta x)$, $(y, y + \Delta y)$ and $(z, z + \Delta z)$. After $\delta t$, the side along $x$ will lengthen from $\Delta x$ to $\Delta x + \Delta x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta t = \Delta x \left(1 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta t \right)$. Similarly, the side along $y$ will lengthen from $\Delta y$ to $\Delta y \left(1 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \delta t \right)$, and the side along $z$ lengthens from $\Delta z$ to $\Delta z \left(1 + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \delta t \right)$. Consequently the volume $V(t) = \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z$ will change to
\begin{equation}
V(t + \delta t) = \Delta x \left(1 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta t \right) \Delta y \left(1 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \delta t \right) \Delta z \left(1 + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \delta t \right) = V(t) \left[1 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right) \delta t + O(\delta t)^2 \right]
\end{equation}
Hence, the rate of volume dilatation is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \frac{1}{V} \frac{V(t + \delta t) - V(t)}{\delta t} = \frac{1}{V} \frac{dV}{dt} = \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right) = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}
\label{1.2.12}
\end{equation}
Next, the off-diagonal terms. Referring to Figure given, consider a plane flow in which $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ do not vanish. In the time interval $\delta t$ the side $\Delta x$ rotates counterclockwise for an angle $\delta \theta_1 = \frac{\Delta v \delta t}{\Delta x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \delta t$. The side $\Delta y$ rotates counterclockwise for an angle $\delta \theta_2 = -\frac{\Delta u \delta t}{\Delta y} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \delta t$. The total rate of angular deformation is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta \theta_1}{\delta t} - \frac{\delta \theta_2}{\delta t} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
\label{1.2.13}
\end{equation}
Thus $e_{12} = e_{xy}$ is a rate of angular deformation, called the rate of shear strain. Other components $e_{13}$ and $e_{23}$ can be interpreted similarly.

Question

From the figure, How does $\delta \theta_1 = \frac{\Delta v \delta
 t}{\Delta x}$?

My attempt
From the figure,
I can say that $\tan \delta \theta_1= \frac{\text{Opposite side}}{\Delta x}$, If $\delta \theta_1$ very small, we can say $\tan \delta \theta_1 \approx \delta \theta_1.$
For the opposite side,
I applied the velocity in the $y$ direction.
$ v(x+\Delta x,y,z)=v(x,y,z)+v_x(x,y,z)\Delta x+O(\Delta x^2)$
Neglecting Higher order terms,
$ v(x+\Delta x,y,z)=v(x,y,z)+v_x(x,y,z)\Delta x$
Opposite side$=(v(x,y,z)+v_x(x,y,z)\Delta x)\delta t.$
But answer in the paragraph is different. Opposite side$= \Delta v \delta t$. How does it come?

Do you have the details of the textbook from which the figures are taken?

Yes====>https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/1-63-advanced-fluid-dynamics-of-the-environment-fall-2002/resources/12kinematics/

Near the equation 1.2.13

exaggerated shear diagram with annotations
$\delta\theta_1$ is a counterclockwise angle and hence it has a positive sign;
$\tan\delta\theta_1\approx\delta\theta_1=\frac{\Delta v \delta t}{\Delta x}$.
$\delta\theta_2$ is a clockwise angle and hence it has a negative sign;
$\tan\delta\theta_2\approx\delta\theta_2=-\frac{\Delta u \delta t}{\Delta x}$.
$u$ is the fluid velocity along $x$-direction, $v$ is the fluid velocity along $y$-direction. The deformation $\Delta x$ induces a velocity  $\Delta v$ in the $y$-direction which in turn produces a deformation $\Delta v \delta t$. In the same way the deformation $\Delta y$ induces a velocity  $\Delta u$ in the $x$-direction which in turn produces a deformation $\Delta u \delta t$.

Why $\Delta v \delta t$ not $ v(x+\Delta x, y)\delta t$? Idon't understand the meaning of the symbol $\Delta v$.

Opposite side= velocity at the tip in the $y$ direction times $\delta t$. Right?

@Unknownx the author defines $u$ as the velocity in the $x$-direction and $v$ as the velocity in the $y$-direction. A displacement $\Delta x$ in the $x$-direction induces a change in the velocity $\Delta v$ in the $y$-direction.

Sorry @Ted Black  I don't understand this statement. A displacement $Δx$
in the $x$
-direction induces a change in the velocity $Δv$
in the $y$
-direction. Is my logic wrong? Could you explain with a figure before you used?

On  page 2 the author states that if $\partial v/\partial x$ does not vanish then as for each displacement $\Delta x$ we have a change in velocity from zero to $\Delta v$ in the $y$-direction. This generates a displacement $\Delta v\delta t$ also in the $y$-direction.

you mean displacement at the one end is $v\delta t$ at $x$ other end ($x+\Delta x)$ is $(v+\Delta v)\delta t$. the difference  is $\Delta v\delta t.$ Right?

Since by approximation $\Delta v\approx \partial v /\partial x \Delta x.$

If you know the answer of my new question. Could you help me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4956866/prove-the-energy-equation-of-the-fluid-kinematics
