Prove that the momentum conservation equation of the incompressible fluid($\nabla \cdot \vec v=0$)
Prove that the momentum conservation equation of the incompressible fluid($\nabla \cdot \vec v=0$) is
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \mu \frac{\partial^2 v_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_j} + \rho f_i
\end{equation}
My attempt:-
General Momentum equation is given by
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j}+ \rho f_i
\end{equation}
We know that the for incompressible flow
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{ij} = -p \delta_{ij} + \mu \left( \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right)
\end{equation}
Applying in the above equation. We get
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}(-p \delta_{ij} + \mu \left( \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right))+ \rho f_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}(-p \delta_{ij}) + \mu \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\left( \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right))+ \rho f_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}(-p ) + \mu \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\left( \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right)+ \rho f_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}(-p ) + \mu \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\left( \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} \right) +\mu \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right)+ \rho f_i
\end{equation}
We know that $\delta_{ij}=1$ iff $i=j$
\begin{equation}
\rho \frac{D v_i}{D t} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(-p ) + \mu \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j \partial x_j}\left(v_i\right) +\mu\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\left(v_j\right)+ \rho f_i
\end{equation}
I am not getting the required answer. Where is my mistake?

Remember that your are using Einstein summation convention. This means that:
$$\begin{align*} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\left(v_j\right)&=\sum_j\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j \partial x_i}\left(v_j\right)=\sum_j\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\left(v_j\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\sum_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(v_j\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}0 =0.\end{align*}$$
Where I used that $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ and assume $\vec{v}$ is twice continuously differentiable such that I can interchange the partial derivatives by Schwarz's Theorem.

$ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j \partial x_j}\left(v_i\right)$ means $\sum_j  \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_j \partial x_j}\left(v_i\right)=\nabla^2v_i$?

If possible, could you help me with this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4952689/how-does-delta-theta-1-frac-delta-v-delta-t-delta-x

I'll take a look. But no promises :) If $\nabla^2$ is the Laplace operator, then yes you are correct.

okay. Thank you verymuch
