Prove the energy equation of the fluid kinematics.
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/1-63-advanced-fluid-dynamics-of-the-environment-fall-2002/resources/41energy/
From the Balanced energy equation
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e + \frac{q^2}{2} \right) = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i + \frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} q_i)}{\partial x_j}$
Prove that
$\rho \frac{De}{Dt} + \rho q_i \frac{Dq_i}{Dt} = \rho f_i q_i + q_i \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} - p \frac{\partial q_i}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial (\tau_{ij} q_i)}{\partial x_j}.$
My attempt:-
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e + \frac{q^2}{2} \right) = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i + \frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} q_i)}{\partial x_j}$
Applying Product rule of differntiation,
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e \right)+\rho q_i\frac{D}{Dt}\left( q_i \right)  = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i + \sigma_{ij}\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_j}+q_i\frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} )}{\partial x_j}$
We have $\sigma_{ij}=-p\delta_{ij}+\tau_{ij}$
$p\delta_{ij}-$ Stress due to molecular movement.
$\tau_{ij}-$ Viscous stress.
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e \right)+\rho q_i\frac{D}{Dt}\left( q_i \right)  = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i + (-p\delta_{ij}+\tau_{ij})\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_j}+q_i\frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} )}{\partial x_j}$
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e \right)+\rho q_i\frac{D}{Dt}\left( q_i \right)  = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i -p\delta_{ij}\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_j}+\tau_{ij}\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_j}+q_i\frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} )}{\partial x_j}$
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e \right)+\rho q_i\frac{D}{Dt}\left( q_i \right)  = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i -p\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_i}+q_i\frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} )}{\partial x_j}+\tau_{ij}\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_j}$
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e \right)+\rho q_i\frac{D}{Dt}\left( q_i \right)  = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i -p\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_i}+q_i\frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} )}{\partial x_j}+\tau_{ij}\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_j}$
$\rho \frac{D}{Dt} \left( e \right)+\rho q_i\frac{D}{Dt}\left( q_i \right)  = -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial x_i} + \rho f_i q_i -p\frac{\partial ( q_i)}{\partial x_i}+q_i\frac{\partial (\sigma_{ij} )}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial ( q_i\tau_{ij})}{\partial x_j}-q_i\frac{\partial ( \tau_{ij})}{\partial x_j}$
I don't know how to proceed further. Could you help me?

I think the lecture notes have a typo (forgot to take $\tau_{ij}$ out of the partial). There is another obvious typo on the l.h.s. with $Dq_1/Dt$ instead of $Dq_i/Dt$. By the way which textbook does the lecturer use for this course?

I don't know @TedBlack

Instarted following this notes by trying different other textbooks.

@TedBlack https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4963715/can-we-say-incompressible-fluid-flow-nabla-cdot-vec-v-0-imples-the-the-den could you help me to imagine this?

I would recommend you touch base with a good introduction on the subject like Fluid Mechanics by Frank White.

thank you:)@TedBlack
