Can we say incompressible fluid flow( $\nabla \cdot \vec v=0$ imples the the density is constant?
Can we say incompressible fluid flow( $\nabla \cdot \vec v=0$ imples the the density is constant?( where $\vec v$ is a velocity vector)
My attempt:-
Let $\rho=\rho(\vec x, t)$ be the density of the material volume.
Applying the mass conservation equation
$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla \cdot \rho \vec{v}=0$
We have
$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\rho \nabla \cdot \vec{v}+\vec{v}\cdot \nabla \rho=0$
We know that incompressible flow in many textbook is $\nabla \cdot \vec v=0$
That is
$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot \nabla \rho=0$
I don't know how to prove further.

No need to go further, you have proven it already. Indeed, since the density $\rho$ depends on both space and time, its differential is given by
$$
\mathrm{d}\rho(\vec{x},t) = \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial z}\mathrm{d}z = \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t + \nabla\rho \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{x},
$$
hence the following total time derivative :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla\rho,
$$
where $\vec{v} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}$. Note that the total derivative above is sometimes called the "material derivative", as mentioned by Mattew Cassel in his comment, but it represents nothing else than the derivative of a (bivariate) function, deduced with the help of the chain rule. Finally, since you showed that $\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$, then you can conclude that $\rho = const$.
It has to be highlighted that the condition $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = 0$ alone wouldn't be sufficient, because it would mean that the density $\rho$ doesn't depend directly on time, but it could still evolve indirectly through $\vec{x}$, the latter being itself time-dependent $-$ whose indirect contribution is given precisely by the advective term $\vec{x} \cdot \nabla\rho$. That is why a zero total derivative is required to conclude that $\rho$ is constant.
